# Is there a straightforward way in R to extract different parts of the end of a complex string into multiple separate columns?

Tags: r, regex, string

I apologize if my question is long winded. I have downloaded data from the Census API on American Indian Tribal Areas and my data frame ("data") looks like this:

```
                           NAME     
1   Penobscot Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, ME
2   Poarch Creek Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, AL--FL 
3   Turtle Mountain Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, MT--ND--SD
4   Coos, Lower Umpqua, and Siuslaw Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, OR
```

I would like to separate out the state abbreviations at the ends of the NAME values. The geographies span 1, 2, or 3 states and I would like to have 3 separate state variables, so that the end result would be:

```
                           NAME                                                     state1   state2  state3
1   Penobscot Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, ME                          ME
2   Poarch Creek Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, AL--FL                   AL       FL
3   Turtle Mountain Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, MT--ND--SD            MT       ND      SD
4   Coos, Lower Umpqua, and Siuslaw Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, OR    OR
```

So far I've done the following:

```
# separate states from end of values in NAME column
data$states <- sub('.*, ', '', data$NAME)

#remove "--" from states values
data$st_split <- strsplit(data$states, "--")
```

The data now looks like:

```
       NAME             states           st_split     
1    ..., ME              ME                 ME
2    ..., AL--FL        AL--FL         c("AL", "FL")
3    ..., MT--ND--SD   MT--ND--SD   c("MT", "ND", "SD")
4    ..., OR
```

I'm stuck on where to go from here. This is probably basic R right now that I should know, so I apologize in advance.

I'm not sure how to get out the individual state abbreviations from st_split or if there's an easier way that I should have used from the beginning.

Thanks in advance!

**data**

```
data <- data.frame(NAME = c(
'Penobscot Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, ME',
'Poarch Creek Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, AL--FL',
'Turtle Mountain Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, MT--ND--SD',
'Coos, Lower Umpqua, and Siuslaw Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, OR'))
```

Comment: Try `library(stringr)` with `str_match(x, "^(.*?)(?:,\\s*([A-Z]{2}))?(?:--([A-Z]{2}))?(?:--([A-Z]{2}))?$")[,-1]`, see [demo](https://rextester.com/ZRUM60391)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that should be an answer. I got the same result in about 6 lines of pedestrian code that I'd be embarrassed to post under your comment.

Comment: @AllanCameron Ok, [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59995989/3832970) with some explanations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. Shame I can only upvote it once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("Penobscot Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, ME", "Poarch Creek Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, AL--FL", "Turtle Mountain Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, MT--ND--SD", "Coos, Lower Umpqua, and Siuslaw Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, OR")
str_match(x, "^(.*?)(?:,\\s*([A-Z]{2}))?(?:--([A-Z]{2}))?(?:--([A-Z]{2}))?$")[,-1]
```

Output:

```
     [,1]                                                                        
[1,] "Penobscot Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land"                      
[2,] "Poarch Creek Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land"                   
[3,] "Turtle Mountain Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land"                
[4,] "Coos, Lower Umpqua, and Siuslaw Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land"
     [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "ME" NA   NA  
[2,] "AL" "FL" NA  
[3,] "MT" "ND" "SD"
[4,] "OR" NA   NA
```

See the [R demo](https://rextester.com/ZRUM60391).

The regex is

```
^(.*?)(?:,\s*([A-Z]{2}))?(?:--([A-Z]{2}))?(?:--([A-Z]{2}))?$
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/pXSiS1/1). It captures the first characters up to the two letters, that are optionally followed with `--` and two uppercase ASCII letters and then an identical optional group before the end of the string. Only the necessary parts are captured, and the `str_match` function keeps the captures in its output.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?:,\s*([A-Z]{2}))?` - an optional group matching `,`, 0+ whitespaces, and then capturing into Group 1 any two ASCII uppercase letters
- `(?:--([A-Z]{2}))?` - an optional group matching `--` and then capturing into Group 2 any two ASCII uppercase letters
- `(?:--([A-Z]{2}))?` - an optional group matching `--` and then capturing into Group 3 any two ASCII uppercase letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks so much for this detailed answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

I use library data.table for just about everything.  You can try this.

```html
library(data.table)

A <- data.table(st_split = list("ME",c("AL","FL"),c("MT","ND","SD")),id=c(1:3))

A[,new1:=st_split[[1]][1],by=id]
A[,new2:=st_split[[1]][2],by=id]
A[,new3:=st_split[[1]][3],by=id]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use *unglue*

```r
library(unglue)
patterns = c("{description=.*}, {state1}--{state2}--{state3}",
             "{description=.*}, {state1}--{state2}",
             "{description=.*}, {state1}")

unglue_unnest(data, NAME,  patterns)
#>                                                                  description
#> 1                       Penobscot Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land
#> 2                    Poarch Creek Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land
#> 3                 Turtle Mountain Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land
#> 4 Coos, Lower Umpqua, and Siuslaw Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land
#>   state1 state2 state3
#> 1     ME   <NA>   <NA>
#> 2     AL     FL   <NA>
#> 3     MT     ND     SD
#> 4     OR   <NA>   <NA>
```

We type `{description=.*}` to make it gready, as `{description}` would be equivalent to `{description=.*?}` and would stop at the first comma.

The order of patterns is also important here because the first pattern that matches will be applied, and the last patterns matches all so would be the only one applied if the order were reversed.